# Get info from a running process

Tags: c#

I have two console applications, A & B.
I want to run A and attach to it a variable, flag or something else that can be read from B.

When I start B, this process searches for A by name. If A is running i want to get some information from it, for now a simple boolean value is enought.

I found

- ManagementObjectSearcher in order to get a value from the command line parameter, and it's ok
- Get a environment variable seems to verbose

any other solution?

Comment: Looks like a scenario for WCF if you really want some Kind of interprocess communication - but might be a bit heavy weight for your requirements. Can you store the variable, e.g. in the file system or a database? Also, you could start B from A and provide the variable as a command line argument.

Comment: The simplest way is a named Mutex, use OpenExisting() to see if it is there.  Gives you a true/false outcome.  That's rarely where it ends, plenty of other choices for process interop in .NET.  Like a named pipe, socket, remoting or WCF.

Comment: I'll try Mutex to get a single instance of A running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) are one of the fastest way to do IPC (inter-process communication) on the same machine.

Comment: I'l keep A listening and B will check for it